# Python - Identity Matching Service (Machine Learning?)

Tags: python, matching, levenshtein-distance, fuzzy

I have a **huge** database of customers and a very small set of data of persons (which could be customers)

Both data sets contains information like:

Lastname, Firstname, Street, ZIP, City, etc.

**What I want:**

I want to check with Python, if the small set of persons are our customers. And if one of them is our customer, WHICH one is the correct customer (problems: misspelling, duplicates are possible, if only some information are given) The service should give me something like the top 5 search results of one Person.

**What I already have:**

Normalization of both data sets (remove: extensions, lowercase, punctuation, etc)

Right now im struggling on the next steps. Should I calculate the Levenshtein Distance for every field, **if** the data is available? Should I normalize the data before matching or within the matching? I feel like calculate every field distance in my complete customer database is slowing down the script.

I appreciate some help if you can give me some tips for a fast & fuzzy matching service.

Comment: There's really no right/wrong way, but I think intuitively, I would approach the problem in a hierarchical way. First calculate the distance on the first and last names. If the distance > 0.8, then perform an exact match on ZIP, otherwise move to next customer. If there is a match on Zip, then perform distance calculations on remaining fields, otherwise move to next customer. Finally, calculate a weighted average metric of distances, where heavier weights are assigned to the more granular fields (e.g. street, first, last) and lighter weights to less granular (e.g. city, zip). Sort and report.